# Off Topic - Prior research, why only translation requests?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, close-reasons, translation

Just by looking at [this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/11003/etymology-and-usage-of-freuen-and-froh) one can see, that a great part of it can be answered by a small google search and some intensive thinking.

> Is there an etymological connection between **these two words**["freuen", "froh"] that share a **similar** meaning? And also, do they share the **same** meaning?

Reading through this I thought to myself: these words have a similar meaning and they look somewhat similar, the logical comclusion is: they are derived from the same word originally.

Now as @elena posted a [comment concerning research effort](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/11003/etymology-and-usage-of-freuen-and-froh#comment27810_11003) and nothing happened for 2 Hours, I decided to apply a close vote, as this question obviously did **not** show prior research effort whatsoever. This does not mean there was none, OP clearly stated "[the words] share a similar meaning", which means he at least looked them up in a dictionary, but no mention of that.

Thus I navigated to the Off-Topic close reasons and to my surprise found the following wording:

> Questions **asking for translations**[*sic*] are off-topic [...]

Why do we restrict ourselves to translation requests only? Why not instead have following close-reason:

> Questions that are not clearly indicating prior **research effort** are off-topic.[...]

Comment: What’s wrong with “asking for translations”?

Comment: In itself nothing, but it's restricting the close-reasons for the in fact same thing: a low-quality question, that should contain / show research effort

Answer (score 4):

The difference is this:

- Questions on any topic should be only asked after prior research effort. If a question can be easily solved by a short research, it should be closed. In this case the close vote should usually be accompanied by a comment linking to a Wikipedia article or similar to demonstrate the lack of effort. However, in general, questions are not required to elaborate on the prior research effort.
- Questions on translations and similar have to indicate prior research effort from the very beginning. Such a question without indications of prior research effort can be closed without further comment. The burden of proof is shifted to the asker.