# Why should somebody consult an online translation service before asking here?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, community-moderation, translation

Community recently downvoted and closed this question as *off topic*:

[How do you say "He was looking for you" in German?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/43470/how-do-you-say-he-was-looking-for-you-in-german)

The given canned close reason "requests for proofreading, spell checking or translations **of individual texts** are off topic" does not fit here, because there neither is such an individual text nor is there anything in that question that could be "narrowed further down". I believe it was more of a **phrase request** [that we previously had decided to be on topic](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1093/what-is-a-phrase-request-and-when-do-we-accept-it-as-on-topic).

In a highly upvoted comment it said in addition:

> Did you try to use an online translator? What did it say? Do you have further problems with this translation attempt?

It is not the first time that we could read such a request for using an online translation service but in this case it appears as if it was the only thing what is missing.

Was this really the only reason for closing this question as *off topic*? What would make the result of such a machine translation so valuable here?

If not, what else do you think is missing to this question to make it on topic? What should have been said to help making this question or similar future questions better?

Comment: Hi Takkat, why did you accept the answer from @Wrzlprmft already? IMHO it is too early and can not be seen as community consensus.

Comment: @Thomas well, +6 is about the most we can get here. If a better answer will be added people can always still vote on that or we will accept the other answer then

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why should somebody consult an online translation service before asking here?

I think that consulting an automatic translation services should never be mandatory and given their inevitable shortcomings, I would not recommend them either in most cases. Consulting such a service can be one way of prior research in some cases, but that’s about it.

> Was this really the only reason for closing this question as *off topic*?

Let’s walk through [this scheme](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1104/2594):

1. What does the question ask for? – **translation**
2. Which direction? – **to German**
3. Is the meaning of the foreign words clear? – **yes**
4. Is the question about a single world, idiom or fixed phrase? – I can see why this might be debatable, but I would say **yes**, it is. In particular, some of the answers (e.g., “Y wollte etwas von Dir.”) would not come up when translating piece by piece.
5. Does the asker explain why a dictionary did not help? – **no**
6. Do you expect that a **simple** look-up in any dictionary suffices to answer the question? – Again, I can understand why this is debatable: I can imagine that a dictionary contains this phrase. However, I consulted a few dictionaries and found nothing, so: **no**
7. Is the question clear? – **yes**. More details would help us to provide a more helpful answer to the asker, but it is clear what is a good answer to this question.

Comment: Nice scheme but I am missing your conclusion. However this forced me to follow your link.  So I understand it. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

A principle in most SE-sites is "**Show your own effort!**" I think this principle rules for German SE, too. And in this sense, it is not too much to ask to use an online translator<sup>1</sup>, to look if it answers the question and (only) if it does not then to ask, especially what is furthermore unclear.

I think, most people here are glad to help but no one wants to be exploited. I think the question mentioned above can be answered with the help of an online tranlator but I also understand that nevertheless it will remain some finer points, e. g. using in formal or colloquial way and so on.

So for me, in deed this question only lacks the "own effort" and that's why I wrote the comment mentioned above.

<sup>1: Like Google tranlslator, DeepL and so on.</sup>

Comment: Just so we are on the same page: Can you specify what you mean when you say *online translator?*

Comment: The question is: does lack of own effort make a question *off topic*? You approach to ask for a further clarification what questions remain after consulting an online translation service is perfectly fine but it is new to me that lack of effort should make a question off topic. If any reason *unclear* may be disputable but people voted to close this question as off topic. This is what I do not understand.

Comment: Accordint to [this meta question](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/628/): yes, it would be *off topic*. The [help center](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) also mention it as second bullet.

Comment: **But:** I don't think, we should close such questions immediately. That's why I aks for improvement (clarification) to give the OP the chance to fill in his search results and the remaining problems.

Comment: @IQV: yeah I can see this clearly and I know it was not you who closed the question. **But:** on-topicness and high quality sometimes go together but by no means not always. An on topic question does not necessarily be a good one and vice versa. That is what voting on questions **and editing** is all about.

Comment: For phrase-requests we had this meta discussion: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1093/what-is-a-phrase-request-and-when-do-we-accept-it-as-on-topic

Comment: And for translation requests, prior research and off-topic [this meta discussion](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/647/).

Comment: @IQV: but what if this was not such a translation request of an inidvidual text but rather a phrase request? And, I really don't want to see a flood of questions with a line *Google translates this as follows ... *.

Comment: Then for me, it would be not off-topic but an allowed question. But it needs both elements: a translation attempt with a dictonary (or at least an online translator - no matter how bad they are) **and** an explanation, what is unclear.

Comment: @IQV: that is exactly what I mean - the question lacks an explanation about what is unclear but it is not *off topic* (we have many similar questions here, often with little research effort too). So your comment is perfectly fine but the closure without any other explanation is not.

Comment: @IQV: "I don't think, we should close such questions immediately. That's why I aks for improvement (clarification)" - that is exactly what putting a question "on hold" means on SE. It is not "closed" as in "rejected, never to be touched again". It is put "on hold", i.e. certain actions such as posting answers are disabled until the OP has come back to improve their question. In other words, if you think a question *needs* to be improved to become answerable and/or useful for the scope of an SE site, putting it *on hold* immediately is the way to go.